# Visual Studio ASPX designer doesn't render css correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, designer

Am I the only person experiencing this? Or am I  missing some simple fix?

Web Forms design would not show my page correctly. It basically doesn't try to apply bootstrap classes on my controls. The result is a really awkward-looking layout that would only show correctly when I open it in a browser. Now that can be a real showstopper considering how quickly we want to see how small code changes affect the output and then refine them further. If we have to go to browser after every small change, doesn't it make life miserable for ASP.NET designers?

I have seen this problem in VS2005, VS208, VS2010 and now in VS2013. Isn't it enough time for MS to fix this so very evident issue? Or is there a fix already available?

### Update

Google search brought me to my own post after 2 years. The problem still persists with VS2015 Update 3. What a shame.

Comment: I always setup websites on my local IIS and using it instead of visual studio designer :)

Comment: @MajoB: mmmm... what? Setting up sites on local IIS has anything to do with VS designer?

Comment: I mean if i will to quickly see results then i prefer to refresh browser instead of visual studio designer.

Comment: @MajoB: Ah, then you still miss the enjoyment of working with a designer. Think WinForms or WPF. :)

Comment: Personally, I have given up on the "Visual" part of "Visual Studio" when it comes to web development, but i have found the browser link feature useful (live updates in browser): http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link - you can even sync changes to css the other way as well with the web essentials plugin: http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink